# How to select all items listed in Recyclerview using androidx.recyclerview.selection?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack

I am using `androidx.recyclerview.selection` for selecting items in a `RecyclerView`.
I am trying to build an edit fragment in which it pre-populates the old views in the `RecyclerView`. At present, I was able to load the old values from API call and update the adapter's list by `notifyDataSetChanged` call. But I want all the items in list to be selected in other words I want to add all items somehow to `SelectionTracker` object somehow while the fragment loads.

Whenever `notifyDataSetChanged` is called I could see `SelectionTracker`'s observer `onSelectionRefresh()` is triggered but I couldn't update the selection tracker there since it is going on infinite call loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SelectionTracker.setItemsSelected](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/SelectionTracker#setItemsSelected(java.lang.Iterable%3CK%3E,%20boolean)):

```kotlin
selectionTracker?.setItemsSelected(listOfKeysToBeSelected, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val size = documents.size
for(number in 0 until size){
   (tracker as SelectionTracker<Long>?)?.select(number.toLong())
}
```

pass all position of recyclerview using for loop start with 0 to total count of single item.

Answer (score 0):

You select every item in the `RecyclerView` adapter by iteration.

Assuming your key is `Long`:

```
for (i in 0 until recyclerAdapter.itemCount)
    selectionTracker.select(i.toLong())
```